# Alternative for Sudo command in windows

Tags: python, windows, sudo

I want to use the following code in order to make a simple python distribution in windows:

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

What should I use instead of sudo command in windows?

Comment: Run console as administrator. Start -> type cmd -> right click cmd.exe -> Run As Administrator

Comment: This is off topic and has already been asked at superuser.com - [Is there any 'sudo' command for Windows?](http://superuser.com/q/42537/664)

Answer (score 2):

An equivalent for Windows 7 and Vista would be to use [runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525%28WS.10%29.aspx):

> runas.exe `/user:<ComputerName>\<AdministratorAccountName>` python3 setup.py install

According to the same link even:

> runas.exe /user:administrator python3 setup.py install

should suffice.

You can also open the console as an administrator, as pointed out by [J0HN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/882918/j0hn) in the comments:

> Start -> type cmd -> right click cmd.exe -> Run As Administrator

and then simply:

> python3 setup.py install

Answer (score 0):

you just need to run setup.py file as administrator.